# How do I attach a PDF file to an email?

Tags: email, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

I'm trying to attach a PDF file to an e-mail I'm composing, but clicking on attach option shows only image files.

How can I make it show other files / attach other files ?

(Note: I'm using the e-mail client, not the G-mail one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add another file browser besides the built in Gallery.

[ASTRO File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro) should fit the bill nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Go to bottom of attachment list where you see "File" - enter folder. If you downloaded your pdf from "Drive" it will be in the download folder.

Downloading files from "Drive" is easy as well. Enter Drive and locate the pdf file to download. Click on the person icon on the right-hand side of file name. Locate download button. Your on your way.